# PHP, Redis, lock produkt, until price increase and after that unlock it

Tags: php, redis

i have a problem, i work at moment at a onlinegame and there it is possible for example, to buy a product, if a user buy it for 5$, the price increase and this user is the new owner, after that the next user can buy it from the current owner for 6$...
This happens a lot of times every secound. To avoid that a more than one user buy the product at same time i add a redis flag, for examle:

```
buyAction($product_id,...){
    $lock_id = "buy_".$product_id;
    $is_locked = Predis_Interface::get($lock_id);
    if($is_locked) {
        die();
    } else {
        Predis_Interface::set($lock_id, true);
    }
    ...
    // add it to a worker query...
    // if the worker query is finished with this product, it set the lock_id to false
    // Predis_Interface::set($lock_id, false)


}
```

But the problem is, that sometimes more than one user buying the same product for 5$. Therefore both buyers have 5 less $, but only one has the product...

I hope someone can help me with this problem, please.

Comment: The problem is called a race condition and it is due to commands interleaving between you lock's check and acquisition. Look into using Redis' transactions as shown in this Predis example: https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.0/examples/transaction_using_cas.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Itamar,

your answer helps me to find a solution, i used now:

```
$lock_id = "buy_".$product_id;
if (!$redis->setnx($lock_id, true)) {
    die();
}
```

this fix the interval between set and read, and it returns only true if it set it successful.

And later on the query worker, i delete it:

```
$lock_id = "buy_".$product_id; 
$redis->del($lock_id)
```